# Showing two matrices have the same column space and finding a basis for this space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am supposed to show that $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&3&5\\1&4&3\\1&1&9\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\-2&-3&-4\\7&12&17\end{bmatrix}$ have the same column space and then I'm supposed to find a basis for that space.

I see that
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&3&5\\1&4&3\\1&1&9\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&0&11\\0&1&2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\-2&-3&-4\\7&12&17\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&1&2\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
How do I use this information effectively? Does this mean $A$ and $B$ both have $\mathbb{R^2}$ as a column space? If not, why not (or how might I be able to find it)? Also, what would I then do to find a basis for this space? I'm used to find a basis for an individual matrix, not two at the same time.

Comment: The column space is 2 dimensional, but if you think its going to have the 3rd component is zero, multiply $A$ or $B$ by a random vector and you will see this is not the case.

Comment: 1) to find a basis for the column space you should perform column operations not row operations. 2) A basis for the column space of $A$ is also a basis for the column space of $B$ since they are the same. But you first have to show that they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce *by columns* both matrices:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&3&5\\1&4&3\\1&1&9\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&\!\!-2\\1&\!\!-2&4\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\1&\!\!-2&0\end{pmatrix} $$

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\\!\!-2&\!\!-3&\!\!-4\\7&12&17\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&2\\1&\!\!-2&\!\!-4\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\1&\!\!-2&0\end{pmatrix}$$

As you can see, both reduction yield the same two linearly independent columns (first two from the left) which are then a basis for the column space in both cases.

Of course, instead of doing column elementary operations, which is usually harder for most of us, you can simply take the transpose of both matrices and carry on rows reduction.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a basis for the column space of $A$ by considering the linearly independent columns of $A$. You can also use linearly independent columns from any equivalent matrix. Fortunately, you've already found equivalent matrices by row-reduction.

For the matrix which is equivalent to $A$, it isn ot hard to see that the first two columns are linearly independent, while the third is dependent on the other two. Thus, the column space of $A$ is two dimensional and the first two columns give a basis for that space.

Now, using the same arguements for $B$, what can you conclude?

Answer (score 0):

A simple working rule: Reduce the matrix to its echelon form. The columns containing the pivots in the original matrix are the basis of the column space.

Comment: This is wrong, I think: for example in the OP's question, the two columns containing the pivots **cannot** be a basis for the column space as, for example, the vector $\;(5,3,9)^t\;$ = the third column of $\;A\;$ , isn't in their span.

Comment: @Timbuc: Let $A_1,A_2,A_3$ be the three columns of $A$ in order. Then $11A_1-2A_2=A_3$.

Comment: I know that. I understood your answer as saying that the columns with the pivots are a basis, but now it looks like you meant the *original* columns in the *original* matrix.